# destroy uiviewcontroller containing UIWebView when playing video?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uiviewcontroller

Hey all... I have a view controller (A) which on some action, alloc init's another view controller (B) and then adds B's view to its view as a subview. So now ViewController B's view is a subview of ViewController A. The problem I have is If I simply remove B's view from A it seems to still stick around for example. View B contains a web view, when I load a video on the webView, even after I remove the view from view Controller A's view I can still hear the video??

How can I destroy viewcontroller B and remove its subview from A? Im finding this tricky as I dont really push it onto a navigationcontroller's stack which I can just pop from... I hope this makes sense, if not please say and I will try and clarify.

Many thanks

Jules

```
 -(void)showNewsWebView:(int)index {

NewsWebViewController *myWebView = [[[NewsWebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewsWebViewController" bundle:nil]autorelease];

//setup webview with request etc

[[self.view.superview superview] addSubview:myWebView.view];
myWebView.alpha = 0.
[UIView beginAnimations:@"test" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];
myWebView.view.alpha = 1.;
[UIView commitAnimations];

}

//called after delegate callback from webviewcontroller
- (void)newsWebViewDismissedView:(NewsWebViewController *)controller {
[UIView beginAnimations:@"test" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];
controller.view.alpha = 0.0;
[self performSelector:@selector(removeView:) withObject:controller.view afterDelay:.5];

[UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void) removeView:(UIView *)view {
[view removeFromSuperview];
view = nil;
}
```

Comment: Please provide simplified code. Baring that, why aren't you just pushing and popping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does ViewController B really need to be a ViewController?

If you're adding subviews you should probably have B subclass UIView instead of UIViewController. Adding B's view as a subview essentially negates any advantage you'd have of B being a ViewController.

Anyway to answer your question. You might want to make viewcontroller B an ivar of A so that viewcontroller A can manage the memory of viewController B. Once you remove the view of B from A, you can release viewcontroller B from memory (I still don't support this as it sounds like ineffective code. You should probably state what you're aiming to do, and post some code as to how you're doing it so we can help you out better :) )

EDIT:

From your code seems like you should just be pushing and popping. Are you using MyWebViewController just to show a webpage? You might be better off using a simple UIWebView.

I also noticed something wrong in your animation code for setting alpha to 0. If you want some method to be executed after an animation ends you should use the following code:

```
//called after delegate callback from webviewcontroller
- (void)newsWebViewDismissedView:(NewsWebViewController *)controller {
[UIView beginAnimations:@"test" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(removeView)];

controller.view.alpha = 0.0;

[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response, please see code above. I think u might be right about the need for B to be a viewcontroller.

Comment: I just wrote a comment here but its disappeared?! Anyway thanks for the tip on setAnimationdidStopSelector... I'll use that. My WebController doesnt just show a webview, there are controls in there to share, email, like and close the page so cant really just show a webview. I tried setting the WebController as an ivar and releasing it when I remove the view but this has no effect, the video just keeps playing!!?? Very strange. Any other thoughts? Thanks again for the help so far.

Comment: Hmmm.... You can still do those things with a subclassed UIView. It shouldn't be that difficult. Apart from that, I don't know what's going on here. I do have one solution (which honestly, I feel is quite bad as it's going to result in a memory leak). Depending on how desperate you are to have that video stop playing, you could implement the following method. UIWebView allows you to load a local HTML string using loadHTMLString http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006950-CH3-SW10

Comment: Use a simple local string like <html><body></body></html>. Just before you're about to release controller B, load that local HTML string to have the webview navigate away from the video page. That will stop the video from playing. Again, I want to stress on the fact that this is not the correct solution. The best solution would be to subclass a UIView and have all your controls and the UIWebView on top of that. Adding another view controller's view as a subview somewhere else is fundamentally wrong.

Comment: I think you are correct about the adding of another VC's view but its still driving me crazy with this memory thing. Ive reposted here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267425/memory-bad-access

Answer (score 0):

```
ViewControllerB *vc = [[[ViewControllerB alloc] initWithNibName:@"SomeNib" bundle:nil] autorelease];
```

This should do the trick.  Autoreleasing the view controller at the end of its initial allocation should tell the application to deallocate it after you remove the view from viewcontroller A since nothing else is holding a retain value on it.  Though using a navigation controller might be an easier solution if you are willing to rework your code to push and pop the view instead

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, I tried using autorelease already but I get bad access straight away... I'll post some code in my original question so u can see whats going on. Many thanks again.

Comment: In that case, I'd just set up a variable in your header file `UIViewController *vcB` so after you create your second viewcontroller, put `vcB = myWebView;`.  Then when you want to get rid of the view, call `[vcB.view removeFromSuperview];` and `[vcB release];`

Comment: haha I have tried that exact thing and I still get bad access. Not really sure where to go... I even posted another question here.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267425/memory-bad-access

Comment: using that last comment, do you still have `autorelease` when allocating it?  that would crash the app because it's trying to release the webView twice, which gives it bad access.  if you haven't already, try it without `autorelease` and (hopefully) it'll work for you

Comment: nevermind, i just saw your other question and see there's no autorelease there.  i'll try to think up a reason for it and leave an answer if i can think of one