# memory bad access?

Tags: iphone, memory, exc-bad-access

How can this statement ever give me bad access?

```
myWebView = [[NewsWebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewsWebViewController" bundle:nil];
[[self.view.superview superview] addSubview:myWebView.view];

 if(myWebView!=nil) {
    [myWebView release];
    myWebView = nil;
}
```

Ive ran it through instruments and it crashes every time. myWebView is an ivar in my header file.

Any thoughts? Many thanks

Jules

Comment: What does the crash log show?

Comment: Is that extra '[' and the lack of a semicolon in your first statement a typo or an error in the code?

Comment: @Greg thats a typo and @Deepak whats the best way to get info from the crash. I dont get anything in the console just program received signal : bad access (in auto release pool).

Comment: Two things: (1) when you say ivar, are you declaring it as a property as well? (2) What happens if you do everything within the scope of the method you're working from? Does the app run OK?

Comment: To get detailed crash info you should compile and run the program in debug mode. If a crash occurs, it tells you the exact line of code where the program crashed, and also the sequence of events leading to the crash. Always have NSZombieEnabled set to YES when debugging(A quick google search should tell you how to do this). Setting it to YES gives you information about which object caused the EXC_BAD_ACCESS. EXC_BAD_ACCESS occurs when you try to access an object which has already been released from memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok here is the actual issue. When I removed the webview it gets dealloc'd but I didnt set its delegate to nil. Therefore webViewDidFinishLoading etc was trying to access it and giving me bad access.

Thanks to all for your input.

Answer (score 0):

You should check that myWebView is nil before you add it's view to a subview.  You do not need to set myWebView to nil after you release it.

Comment: Its just a habit to set set it to nil, it does no harm. I'll try checking myWebView before adding.

Comment: I tried the check which did nothing unfortunately, but I might have guessed that as it does show the webView

Comment: I suspect the issue outside of this code and the crash here is a side-effect.  Does it crash if you do not release myWebView?  What is the crash log?

Answer (score -2):

You are setting mywebview to nil after releasing so it crashes as the object no longer exists. Do it in this order:

```
if(myWebView!=nil) {

  myWebView = nil;
  [myWebView release];

}
```

Comment: U can set an object to nil after releasing it

Comment: You'll leak the reference if you do it this way.

Comment: was that for me or @Robert jOk? ie am I leaking or the example is leaking?

Comment: @Jules - the example is leaking. If you set myWebView to nil before you call release on it, you lose the reference, and will be unable to release it. Objective-C allows you to send a message to a nil object, which is why this code would compile/run.